# Read a binary file using unpack in Python compared with a IDL method

Tags: python, numpy, binary, idl-programming-language

I have a IDL procedure reading a binary file and I try to translate it into a Python routine.
The IDL code look like :

```
a = uint(0)
b = float(0)
c = float(0)
d = float(0)
e = float(0)
x=dblarr(nptx)
y=dblarr(npty)
z=dblarr(nptz)
openr,11,name_file_data,/f77_unformatted
readu,11,a
readu,11,b,c,d,e
readu,11,x
readu,11,y
readu,11,z
```

it works perfectly. So I'm writing the same thing in python but I can't find the same results (even the value of 'a' is different). Here is my code :

```
x=np.zeros(nptx,float)
y=np.zeros(npty,float)
z=np.zeros(nptz,float)
with open(name_file_data, "rb") as fb:
    a, = struct.unpack("I", fb.read(4))
    b,c,d,e = struct.unpack("ffff", fb.read(16))
    x[:] = struct.unpack(str(nptx)+"d", fb.read(nptx*8))[:]
    y[:] = struct.unpack(str(npty)+"d", fb.read(npty*8))[:]
    z[:] = struct.unpack(str(nptz)+"d", fb.read(nptz*8))[:]
```

Hope it will help anyone to answer me.

Update : As suggested in the answers, I'm now trying the module "FortranFile", but I'm not sure I understood everything about its use.

```
from scipy.io import FortranFile
f=FortranFile(name_file_data, 'r')
a=f.read_record('H')
b=f.read_record('f','f','f','f')
```

However, instead of having an integer for 'a', I got : array([0, 0], dtype=uint16).

And I had this following error for 'b': Size obtained (1107201884) is not a multiple of the dtypes given (16)

Answer (score 1):

According to [a table of IDL data types](http://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/IDL_Data_Types.html), `UINT(0)` creates a *16 bit integer* (i.e. two bytes).  In the [Python `struct` module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/struct.html), the `I` [format character](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/struct.html#format-characters) denotes a 4 byte integer, and `H` denotes an unsigned 16 bit integer.

Try changing the line that unpacks `a` to

```
    a, = struct.unpack("H", fb.read(2))
```

Unfortunately, this probably won't fix the problem.  You use the option `/f77_unformatted` with `openr`, which means the file contains more than just the raw bytes of the variables.  (See the [documentation of the OPENR command](http://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/open.html) for more information about `/f77_unformatted`.)

You could try to use [`scipy.io.FortranFile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.FortranFile.html) to read the file, but there are no gaurantees that it will work.  The binary layout of an unformatted Fortran file is compiler dependent.

Comment: I tried but all the values are always different. 
idl: a=0; b=10000.000 c=31.820000 etc
python: a=4, b=0.0. c=3.67e-40